# Why isn't my function working even though the loop inside the function is

Tags: r, function, loops

I wrote this function:

```
calculate_percentage = function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    x[i] = x[i]*100/x[length(x)]
    return(x)
  }
}
```

but when I applied this function to any vector, it doesn't work. The vector remains unaltered. The loop inside the function itself, however, works just fine. Could someone explain to me please?

Comment: Please post sample data using dput() and the code where you apply to the function to a vector

Comment: The `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, the function will exit after the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Note that `x*100/tail(x,1)` would do what you want without a for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
calculate_percentage = function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    x[i] = x[i]*100/x[length(x)]

  }
  return(x)
}


x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

x <- calculate_percentage(x)
```

I guess you want to return the percentage transformation of all the values so I moved the return outside of the loop